# What is the difference between finding the antiparticle and charge conjugated state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

I'm a bit confused about the difference of the charge conjugated state (applying C-operator) and the antiparticle of a certain particle.

As an example:
To get the antiparticle of the $\Sigma^-$ $(dds)$ baryon, as far as I know, we have to apply a CPT-transformation. Well I learned to simply "convert all quarks to their antiquarks", i.e. $\overline{\Sigma^-}$, which results in $(\bar{d}\bar{d}\bar{s})$. For a $\pi^+$ $(u \bar{d})$ this would end up in $(\bar{u} d)$ which relates to $\overline{\pi^+} = \pi^-$.

Now to get the charge conjugated state, I would apply the C-Operator on $\Sigma^-$ which inverts all charge like additive quantum numbers (such as lepton/baryon number, flavour, charge, isospin, strangeness, etc.) which leads me to the same results as for the antiparticle.

So my question is, is the charge conjugated state of a certain particle always its anti-state or are they only equal, because in my example I take a particle at rest instead of a wavefunction, so T- and P-transformations don't have any effects on it?